# How to turn a function into string in python 3

Tags: python, string, function

I'm trying to use askdirectory from tkinter.filedialog. 
The output I get from askdirectory is a function. But for my program I need it to be the string.
In other words, when the user selects the folder it wants to open I need the program to save the path to the folder that the user selected.

I'm then using glob to open all the files, but glob is not accepting a function as input only the string with the folder path.
Does anyone know how to turn it into a String?

I tried the following:

```
  path= askdirectory()
  paths = str(path)
  paths = paths.replace('/', '\\')
```

Comment: First add your code and what you have tried , explain your issue then we can help and its not a free code service .

Comment: Can you show your actual code? It sounds like you just need to *call* the function, rather than only referencing it. There's no callbacks or weird stuff going on where a function should get returned to you.

Comment: `askdirectory` returns the directory _name_ as a string, not a function. What makes you think it returns a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what youve tried.. but this should be fairly to implement for you?
The askdirectory() function WILL output a string when used.. So I'm unsure what you have done to get it returning something different.

As far as opening files with glob, could you provide an example of what you want with this? And I may be able to help. Show some code you have tried maybe?

```
from tkinter import filedialog
dir_choice = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

The above code will store the directory that the user selected. For example, you could do the following:

```
print(dir_choice)
```

and the output would be something like:

```
C:/lorem/ipsum/somedirectory
```

**EDIT**
I answered before you updated your question, but simply using what you already have and doing `print(path)` would work, you don't need the extra two lines.

```
path = askdirectory()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It turns out you are right. It is a string. But glob cant open it because the replace function does not replace / with \\ 
Glob needs it to be C:\\Users\\, but the code I made only changes it to C:\Users\
Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Could you show me your code for opening the file with glob?